# How to shift figures up to make a better looking layout

Tags: css, html

I want to shift some of my figure elements up and over to get a 3x2 table look on my website. It's currently a 2x3, and I'm not sure how to shift the figures around. I would love any help you guys could give me.

here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<section>
        <article>
        <figure class="fig">
            <img src="parks/arches.jpg" alt="Arches" />
            <figcaption>
            Arches National Park
            </figcaption>
        </figure>   
        <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/glacier.jpg" alt="Glacier" />
        <figcaption>
        Glacier National Park
        </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/teton.jpg" alt="Teton" />
        <figcaption>Grand Teton National Park</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/yellowstone.jpg" alt="Yellowstone" />
        <figcaption>Yellowstone National Park</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/yosemite.jpg" alt="Yosemite" />
        <figcaption>Yosemite National Park</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/zion.jpg" alt="Zion" />
        <figcaption>Zion National Park</figcaption>
        </figure>

        </article>
      </section>

      <footer>
        <p>Get out and explore! &copy; 2017 <a href="#">Explore This World and Our Country and Other Stuff</a>.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!--end wrap div-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
figure.fig{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin:5px, 5px, 0, 5px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:black;



}

figure.fig img{
    width:250px;
    padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;

}
figure.fig figcaption
{
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Times New Roman;

}
```

Comment: probably look at using `%` instead of fixed widths in your `figure.fig` and `figure.fig img` style declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this correction in your code, `figure tag` has some default `margin`, which on starting set to `0px` then you added `padding` which was breaking that `grid` and yes instead of `pixels` use `%` as below,

```css
figure{
 margin:0; 
}
.fig{
  width:28%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:black;
  float:left;
  margin:2%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.fig > figcaption{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

```html
 <article>
    <figure class="fig">
        <img src="parks/arches.jpg" alt="Arches" />
        <figcaption>
        Arches National Park
        </figcaption>
    </figure>   
    <figure class="fig">
    <img src="parks/glacier.jpg" alt="Glacier" />
    <figcaption>
    Glacier National Park
    </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
    <img src="parks/teton.jpg" alt="Teton" />
    <figcaption>Grand Teton National Park</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
    <img src="parks/yellowstone.jpg" alt="Yellowstone" />
    <figcaption>Yellowstone National Park</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
    <img src="parks/yosemite.jpg" alt="Yosemite" />
    <figcaption>Yosemite National Park</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="fig">
    <img src="parks/zion.jpg" alt="Zion" />
    <figcaption>Zion National Park</figcaption>
    </figure>

    </article>
  </section>
```